# How to create .htaccess rewrite rules in web.config file for godaddy windows hosting plan

Tags: .htaccess, iis, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, web-config

I am newer to use web.config. I create .htaccess file on my localhost but its not working on godaddy hosting because of windows hosting plan. I don't know how to create rewrite rules in web.config file. My .htaccess rewrite rules are mentioned below.
Please help me. Thanks

```
# Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule home$ index.php?page_id=1 [NC]
RewriteRule blog$ index.php?page_id=2 [QSA]
RewriteRule privacy$ index.php?page_id=3 [NC]
RewriteRule contact$ index.php?page_id=4 [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not create `.htaccess` for IIS. If it's not running Apache it will not work. Web config only works for Windows running IIS. There is nothing that will every get this to work. You either have to convert it to IIS rewrite rules or use a `Linux/Apache` or `Windows/Apache` hosting plan.

Try an online converter site. Here's one that might work. http://www.htaccesstowebconfig.com/

See if this web.config rewrite works.

```
<rule name="rule 1L">
    <match url="home$"  ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?page_id=1"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 2L">
    <match url="blog$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?page_id=2"  appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 3L">
    <match url="privacy$"  ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?page_id=3"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 4L">
    <match url="contact$"  ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?page_id=4"  />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

First empty your web.config file and please try copy above code only and paste in your web.config file
I hope it will work...
Your web.config file must be in root directory...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="rule 1f">
                  <match url="home$"  ignoreCase="true" />
                  <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?page_id=1"  />
                </rule>
                <rule name="rule 2f">
                 <match url="blog$"  />
                 <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?page_id=2" ppendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="rule 3f">
                 <match url="privacy$"  ignoreCase="true" />
                 <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?page_id=3"  />
                </rule>
                <rule name="rule 4f">
                  <match url="contact$"  ignoreCase="true" />
                  <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?page_id=4"  />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Similar situation as above - can someone please confirm if the webconfig below will work?

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
   <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
    <match url="*"/>
     <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
     </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
   </rule></rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>`